# create language code in url for specific language version of the site?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, multilingual, multiple-languages

my site is having three language switcher English, German and Russian using cookies when the visitor clicks the flags. The URL is same for every language.
[image]

Now i want to point url

```
http://www.website.com/ru
```

to the *Russian* version of the site.

Will this be done using .htaccess or with some other method.

How to achieve this.

Comment: What's your Framework or cms? How do you want to pass the language to your PHP code? You don't provide enough informations and code to answer your question.

Comment: Its custom code. what i have created is three flags, when user clicks one of them say Russian, then created a cookie and so calling Russian language file on the basis of cookie. But i want is to when user put url http://website.com/ru then site with Russian version will open. i mean same site and load Russian language file.

Comment: But of course it will be with all urls website.com/ru/contactus.php Or website.com/ru/search.php. I have tried in google but couldn't find any proper method there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [QSA]
```

Now in your PHP code you can get the language with:

```
$lang = isset($_GET['lang']) ? $_GET['lang'] : 'en'; // put your default language last.
```